# How to use PyCharm only as a formatter

Tags: python, pycharm

I have used the regular IDLE python interpreter. Now I discovered PyCharm. It's a really good formatter and has a object hierarchy which I really like and auto-complete.

Unfortunately, PyCharm doesn't have the same interpreter as the regular python IDLE and I can't seem to get it to run w/ the regular python interpreter (Y'know, the one with the rocket in the icon?) and I can't seem to figure out how to get that same interpreter running

If you can give me any suggestions on how to get PyCharm to run on the regular interpreter, that would be nice, as I'm making a text based game, and the Pycharm console isn't great for those.